# How to get directions with Google Maps inside my application

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm currently developing an android app that require Google Maps feature, right now in my android code, i saved the latitude longitude in php server and retrieve back into android app, and it can locate the position. Right now how do i get the direction from my current location to the marker that already set the position from the server?

When i click the marker, there is bottom right corner of the screen that can give direction and map but instead of jumping on to the given google map, how do i set to my current google map which i do not want to use the other google map?

Here is my Android Google Map Code:

```
public class MapsActivity3 extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
    com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener,
    GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener,
    GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener {

MapFragment mapFragment;
GoogleMap gMap;
MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
CameraPosition cameraPosition;
LatLng center, latLng;
String title;
LocationManager locationManager;
Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
Location mLastLocation;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

public static final String ID = "id";
public static final String TITLE = "name";
public static final String LAT = "lat";
public static final String LNG = "lng";

public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;

public static final String TAG = MapsActivity3.class.getSimpleName();

private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

private Marker mSelectedMarker;

private String url = "http://192.168.1.2/gmaps/gmaps.php";

String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
            (this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "GPS is Enabled in your device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        showGPSDisabledAlertToUser();
    }

}

private void showGPSDisabledAlertToUser() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("GPS is disabled in your device. Would you like to enable it?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Goto Settings Page To Enable GPS",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            Intent callGPSSettingIntent = new Intent(
                                    android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                            startActivity(callGPSSettingIntent);
                        }
                    });
    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alert.show();
}

/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    gMap = googleMap;

    center = new LatLng(4.583213, 101.094630);
    cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(center).zoom(15).build();
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

    getMarkers();

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

        buildGoogleApiClient();
        gMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        gMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        gMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);

        //return;
    }
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    //Toast.makeText(this, "buildGoogleApiClient", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

    //mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

private void addMarker(LatLng latlng, final String title) {
    markerOptions.position(latlng);
    markerOptions.title(title);
    gMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    gMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), marker.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity3.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

private void moveToCurrentLocation(LatLng currentLocation)
{
    gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLocation,15));
    // Zoom in, animating the camera.
    gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());
    // Zoom out to zoom level 10, animating with a duration of 2 seconds.
    gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15), 2000, null);

}

private void getMarkers() {
    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.e("Response: ", response.toString());

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                String getObject = jObj.getString("location");
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(getObject);

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    title = jsonObject.getString(TITLE);
                    latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString(LAT)), Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString(LNG)));

                    addMarker(latLng, title);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("Error" , error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity3.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_json_obj);
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }

    Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        //place marker at current position
        //mGoogleMap.clear();
        gMap.clear();
        latLng = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Current Position");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
        mCurrLocationMarker = gMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        //mCurrLocationMarker = mLastLocation;
    }

    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(5000); //5 seconds
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000); //5 seconds
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(0.1F); //1/10 meter

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    Toast.makeText(this,"onConnectionFailed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    /*
     * Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects.
     * If the error has a resolution, try sending an Intent to
     * start a Google Play services activity that can resolve
     * error.
     */
    if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
            /*
             * Thrown if Google Play services canceled the original
             * PendingIntent
             */
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            // Log the error
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        /*
         * If no resolution is available, display a dialog to the
         * user with the error.
         */
        Log.i(TAG, "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLastLocation = location;
    if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
        mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
    }

    // Getting latitude of the current location
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();

    // Getting longitude of the current location
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();

    // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    //LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), true);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
            (this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }

    Location locations = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    List<String> providerList = locationManager.getAllProviders();
    if (null != locations && null != providerList && providerList.size() > 0) {
        locations.getLongitude();
        locations.getLatitude();
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> listAddresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
            if (null != listAddresses && listAddresses.size() > 0) {

                // Here we are finding , whatever we want our marker to show when clicked
                String state = listAddresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                String country = listAddresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                String subLocality = listAddresses.get(0).getSubLocality();
                markerOptions.title("" + latLng + "," + subLocality + "," + state + "," + country);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
    mCurrLocationMarker = gMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Location Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if (mGoogleApiClient != null){
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

}

@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
    mSelectedMarker = null;
}

@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    return false;
}
}
```

Hey guys! Is there a way to change the marker color when i set certain condition on my php like for example:

ID 1 = "Empty space here!"  (marker green color)
ID 2 = "Space occupied!"   (marker red color)

By the way, i can display two marker with two different message

**Edited**

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    gMap = googleMap;
    gMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

    center = new LatLng(4.583213, 101.094630);
    cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(center).zoom(15).build();
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

    getMarkers();

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

        buildGoogleApiClient();
        gMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        gMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        gMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);

        //return;
    }
}
```

**Edit onMarkerClick**

```
@Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    new DirectionsJSONParser();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get direction from one lat,lng location to another, you have to use Google direction api. For simplicity of parsing api response use **google-maps-services-java** library and draw polyline on Map. Following link is very help full for this
https://android.jlelse.eu/google-maps-directions-api-5b2e11dee9b0

Answer (score 2):

To get the direction/path/route, you need google maps directions API. I have done it in my app. So I am pasting here. The answer might be lengthy but it will definitely help you and others.

Write a class that parses Directions API response. Just copy and paste this code. Here is the snippet [link](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/faizan_mubasher_skm/89Edap) as well.

```
public class DirectionJSONParser {

public static final String ROUTES = "routes";
public static final String LEGS = "legs";
public static final String STEPS = "steps";
public static final String POLYLINE = "polyline";
public static final String POINTS = "points";


/**
 * Receives a JSONObject and returns a list of lists containing latitude and longitude
 * @param jObject JSONObject
 * @return List of routes
 */
public List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> parse(JSONObject jObject){

    List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new ArrayList<>();

    JSONArray jRoutes = null;
    JSONArray jLegs = null;
    JSONArray jSteps = null;

    try {

        jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray(ROUTES);
        int jRoutesLength = jRoutes.length();
        // Traversing all routes
        for(int i=0; i<jRoutesLength; i++){

            jLegs = ((JSONObject)jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray(LEGS);

            List path = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            int jLegsLength = jLegs.length();
            // Traversing all legs
            for (int j = 0; j<jLegsLength; j++){

                jSteps = ((JSONObject)jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray(STEPS);

                int jStepsLength = jSteps.length();
                // Traversing all steps
                for (int k = 0; k<jStepsLength; k++){
                    String polyline = "";
                    polyline = (String)((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get(POLYLINE)).get(POINTS);
                    List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(polyline);

                    for (int l = 0; l<list.size(); l++){
                        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();
                        hm.put("lat",Double.toString((list.get(l)).latitude));
                        hm.put("lng",Double.toString((list.get(l)).longitude));
                        path.add(hm);
                    }
                }
            }
            routes.add(path);
        }


    } catch (JSONException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return routes;
}

/**
 * Method to decode polyline points
 * Courtesy : http://jeffreysambells.com/2010/05/27/decoding-polylines-from-google-maps-direction-api-with-java
 * */
private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

    List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<>();
    int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
    int lat = 0, lng = 0;

    while (index < len) {
        int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;

        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;

        LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                (((double) lng / 1E5)));
        poly.add(p);
    }

    return poly;
 }
}
```

Get directions url. It will make complete URL to call api.

```
private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin, LatLng destination) {
    //https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&key=YOUR_API_KEY
    //Origin
    String str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude;
    //Destination
    String str_destination = "destination=" + destination.latitude + "," + destination.longitude;
    // Set output format
    String output = "json";

    String api_key = "key=" + getString(R.string.google_maps_key);

    //Building the parameters to the web service
    String parameters = output + "?" + str_origin + "&" + str_destination + "&" + api_key;

    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + parameters;

    return url;
}
```

Write a method that calls this url and gets response.

```
private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {

    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

    try {

        URL url = new URL(strUrl);

        // Creating an HTTP Connection to communicate with url
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        //Connecting to URL
        urlConnection.connect();

        // Reading data from URL
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = "";

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }

        data = sb.toString();

        bufferedReader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
    } finally {
        iStream.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }

    return data;
}
```

As this is the Network call, call it in separate thread:

```
 /**
 * Fetches data from URL passed
 */
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    // Downloading data in non-UI thread
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        String data = "";
        try {
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

        // Invokes the thread for pars;ing JSON data
        parserTask.execute(result);
    }
}
```

And finally, see the `onPostExecute()` method, it is calling `ParserTask`, here it is:

```
private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {

    // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        JSONObject jObject;
        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
            DirectionJSONParser parser = new DirectionJSONParser();
            routes = parser.parse(jObject);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return routes;
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {


        ArrayList<LatLng> points;
        PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
        int resultSize = result.size();

        //Traversing through all the routes
        for (int i = 0; i < resultSize; i++) {

            points = new ArrayList<>();
            lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

            //Fetching i-th route
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

            int pathSize = path.size();
            // Fetching all the points in i-th route
            for (int j = 0; j < pathSize; j++) {
                HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));

                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                points.add(position);
            }

            // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
            lineOptions.addAll(points);
            lineOptions.width(5);
            lineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);
        }

        if (lastPolyLine != null) {
            lastPolyLine.remove();
        }
        // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
        lastPolyLine = mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
//            mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);

    }
}
```

Where `lastPolyLine` is of `com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline` type.

**NOTE:**

```
if (lastPolyLine != null) {
                lastPolyLine.remove();
            }
```

If you do not put this check, you will end up having multiple paths on every marker click.

In your `onMapReady()` method, set marker click listener and implement `onMarkerClick()`:

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

    Log.i(TAG, "On Marker Click");

    LatLng origin = new LatLng(myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude());
    LatLng destination = marker.getPosition();

    // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
    String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, destination);

    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

    // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
    downloadTask.execute(url);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, is this the way that when i want to get the direction and by not having to launch the google direction map just using my current map?

Comment: Yes this is the way. This is InApp way. You will have it in your own app.

Comment: Hi! I have added your code into my app, but still launching the google direction. I created 1 java class just for DirectionJSONParser. The rest i place at the end of my MapsActivity3.java.

Comment: I didn't find in your code where you are calling `DirectionJSONParser`. If you want to show directions from your location to marker location, first set `mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener()` and then call DirectionJSONParser in thread.

Comment: I'm not sure why after i included `gMap.setOnMarkerClickListener()` in onMapReady(), i no longer can click the marker. Did you mean i just need to call the `DirectionJSONParser` in my `onMarkerClick()` ?  By the way, i have put the edited file.

Comment: it is `gMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this)` not `gMap.setOnMarkerClickListener()`

Comment: Yes i replace into `gMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this)` but still the marker cannot click